# Как передать выбранные значения в Kendo MultiSelect в контроллер

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo

есть две модели со связью многие ко многим:

```
 public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
    public LibraryType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PublicHouse> PublicHouses { get; set; }

}

 public class PublicHouse
{
    [Key]
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }

    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

}
```

В представлении добавления новой книги используется Kendo Milti Select:

```
  @model Library.ViewModels.Models.BookViewModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add book";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Book", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Book Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorName, "Author", new { @class = "control-label" })
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AuthorName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorName)
    <br /><br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, "Year", new { @class = "control-label" })
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing)
    <br /><br />

    @Html.Label("Publication Houses", new { @class = "control-label" })
    <select id="multiselect" style="width:200px"></select>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
                placeholder: "--Select Public Houses--",
                dataTextField: "PublicHouseName",
                dataValueField: "PublicHouseId",
                autoBind: true,
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/book/getallpublichouses"
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <br /><br />

    <input id="bnt-save" type="submit" value="Add Book" />

}
```

Как передать выбранные значения в мультиселекте в контроллер?

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(BookViewModel book)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _bookService.Create(book);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(book);
    }
```